# Remotely reboot computer twice

Tags: powershell, remote-access, invoke-command

I have a scenario where I need to reboot a computer twice, remotely.
My command:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computerName -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
     workflow Reboot {
        Restart-Computer -Wait
        Restart-Computer -Wait
      }
       Reboot
  }
```

But this returns the error

```
Failed to restart the computer com1 with the following error message: A system shutdown is in progress.
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (com1:String) [Restart-Computer], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RestartcomputerFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RestartComputerCommand
    + PSComputerName        : com1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `-Wait` if you are restarting the local computer (which you are doing with the remote session).

Documentation for [Restart-Computer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/restart-computer) states:

> **The Wait parameter is not valid when you are restarting the local computer.** If the value of the ComputerName parameter contains the names of remote computers and the local computer, **Restart-Computer generates a non-terminating error for Wait on the local computer**, but it waits for the remote computers to restart.

You will need to change your command so it does not use Invoke-Command:

```
Restart-Computer -ComputerName $computerName -Credential $cred -Wait
```