# Stop the Service, Restart and Start the service using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to Stop the service, and once the service is stopped i need to reboot the system. After the reboot i need to start the service if it is in stopped state using powershell script.

```
$stage= get-service -name "chrome"

if ( $stage.Status -eq "Running" )
{

Write-Host "The service " $stage.Name "is running"

Stop-Service -Name 'chrome'



}


if ( $stage.Status -eq "Stopped")

{
Restart-Computer -Wait

Start-Service 'chrome'


}
```

Comment: Your script doesn't survive a reboot so you either have to run that script from another computer, make your chrome service automatic started or have a scheduled task at startup to start the chrome service. Far easiest is to set the chrome service to automatic in the service manager (what is the default anyway I believe?!)

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Is my condition is right? or i need to change it. because i need to validate it, once the chrome service is stopped then only i have to perform the restart

Comment: Executing `Restart-Computer -Wait` on your own computer either fails or it ends the script at that point (I don't know, haven't tested it). Either way, in its current form, your `Start-Service 'chrome'` is never reached. Is there a problem setting the chrome service to automatic and have Windows take care of starting it on reboot?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers chrome is just a example service, am looking for other service. When i execute the script its just stopping the service its not moving to next step to reboot the machine

Comment: Your `$stage` variable retains the (some) values of the service for the point in time you have assigned it. You'll need to either reassign the variable or just check it without using a variable

Comment: `Restart-Computer -Wait` doesn't work on the local computer (see my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53389934/remotely-reboot-computer-twice/) for explanation)

Comment: This should be possible when using Powershell Workflows.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to run the code from different server to achieve your goal. as suggested above, once server rebooted, you can't resume back with the same script.

Other than that, there is small change needs to be done you script. which is, you need to call again below code between your if conditions. So that you will get a expected output

$stage= get-service -name "chrome"